Getting "type" : "Buffer" when trying to add a document to mongo db collection using cy.task() as a custom command
In cypress.config.ts, I have defined following.
on('task', {
        async insertOne({ uri, database, collection, document }: { uri: string, database: string, collection: string, document: object }) {
          const client = new MongoClient(uri);
      
          try {
            await client.connect();
            const db = client.db(database);
            const result = await db.collection(collection).insertOne(document);
            return result;
          } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
          } finally {
            await client.close();
          }
        }
      });

In support/commands.ts, I defined that task as following.
Cypress.Commands.add('insertOne', (document) => {
    return cy.task('insertOne', {
      uri: Cypress.env('mongodb').uri,
      database: Cypress.env('mongodb').database,
      collection: Cypress.env('mongodb').collection,
      document: document
    });
  });

In support/e2e.ts, added as below.
declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      insertOne(document: any): Chainable<any>;
    }
  }
}

Finally, calling the custom command in test spec.
const record = {
  userID : '010',
  name : 'Cummins'
};

describe("test db interactions", ()=>{
  it("insert record", ()=>{
    cy.insertOne(record).then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      
    });
  }); 
})


As the result, a new document is inserted to the mongo db collection as following.
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("662c2a31a2da76c3de0047e1"),
    "type" : "Buffer",
    "data" : [
        NumberInt(39),
        NumberInt(0),
        NumberInt(0),
        NumberInt(0),
        NumberInt(2),
        NumberInt(117),
        NumberInt(115),
        NumberInt(101),
        NumberInt(114),
        NumberInt(73),
.....
    ]
}

My expected result is as follow.
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("662abdb145a2efeb31ae10d5"),
    "userID" : "004",
    "name" : "Paul"
}

Installed latest versions of node, cypress-mongodb, and mongodb.
Still trying to learn these stuff, so highly appreciate any help to sort this out. Thanks
